# Set a cell to “Yes” if a cell is "zero" value and "yes" is displayed as color not word

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to build something like this:

```
A     Note

0     Yes (red)     
3     No  (no color/white)  
1     No  (no color/white)  
0     Yes (red)
```

but I want the "yes" and "no" to be displayed as color without the word "yes" or "no".

Comment: You can use conditional formatting and set both don't colour and background to white/ red

Comment: can u explain in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional formatting.

1. Select the cell range you want to apply conditional formatting to (for example, B2:B50).
2. Select **Conditional Formatting** (button in ribbon) > **New Rule...**
3. Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**.
4. Enter formula:

   ```
   =IF($A2=0,TRUE,FALSE)
   ```

   Note: Blank values evaluate to zero, so if you're expecting blanks and want to ignore them, do something like this:

   ```
   =IF(ISBLANK($A2),FALSE,IF($A2=0,TRUE,FALSE))
   ```
5. Select **Format**, select **Fill**, and select the colour red.

Alternatively, if you just want to highlight the cells in column A themselves, then you can simply select the cells and do **Conditional Formatting** > **Highlight Cells Rules** > **Equal To...** 0, then set a custom format with red fill.